# Every set can be well-ordered or not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I don't get it, a book i read on set theory states that every set can be well-ordered, while another book i'm reading, about proofs, says that for example the open interval $(0,1)$ is not well-ordered. How is this possible? I know that the definition states that a non-empty set $S$ is well-ordered if every non-empty subset of $S$ has a least element, but, how can they contradict each other?

Comment: @ $(0,1)$ is not well ordered when you give it the usual ordering. That doesn't mean that there is no well-ordering on it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yeah i realized it right after i asked the question, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You may confuse the *well-orderability* and *being well-ordered*.

The axiom of choice proves every set is *well-orderable*, that is, we can impose a well-order over any set. On the other hand, $(0,1)$ with the natural order is *not* well-ordered. You may well-order the set $(0,1)$, but the well-order does not respect the natural order of the real numbers.